# Flutter - Error occurred when add tab to the page

Tags: flutter, dart, web-applications, flutter-layout

So I have the following code that should display page with button to add tab in the page:

```dart
List<String> tabTitles = [];
List<Widget> tabContents = [];
TabController _tabController;

Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('DataTable of Gene Lists'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => _onTabAdd(_tabController.index),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () => _onTabRemoved(_tabController.index),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
            onPressed: () => _onTabEdit(context),
          ),
        ],
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0),
          child: Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                tabs: tabTitles
                    .map(
                      (title) => Tab(text: title),
                    )
                    .toList(),
                labelColor: Colors.yellow,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                indicatorColor: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

And the function that handle the adding of tab:

```dart
void _onTabAdd(int index) {
    setState(() {
      tabTitles.add("Tab ${tabTitles.length}");
      tabContents.add(GenesTable(this));
      _tabController = TabController(length: tabTitles.length, vsync: this);
    });
  }
```

When I click this button the content seems to load successfully, but the problem is that the titl'es is not shown, and the following error is displayed as you can see in the picture:
[image]

Any help would be appreciate!

### Edit:

I filed an issue on the repo of Flutter, you can follow it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68962)

Comment: you are creating new instance of TabController, try this. 
https://codeshare.io/5000Jv

Comment: You can't, length is final

Comment: exgtract the `TabBar` widget as a `StatefullWidget`, also put `tabcontroller ` inside that `StatefullWidget` ,  pass the list of `Tab`s while creating the instance inside the scaffold body, rebuild whole page and change the list too on actions and it will rebuild new TabBar too. and it will be better to use `List<Widget>.generate` instead of `.map`

Comment: Looks like a bug in flutter itself. Changing the tab controller should just work

Comment: @PietervanLoon It's possible because it's stop working after I update flutter's version

Comment: I’m pretty sure it is. You should probably file an issue there

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve your problem but I found a workaround.

Maybe this will work for you or maybe this will help you actually finding the issue.

Here it is:

```
  void _onTabAdd(int index) {
    tabTitles.add("Tab ${tabTitles.length}");
    tabContents.add(Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    ));
    _tabController = TabController(length: tabTitles.length, vsync: this);
    setState(() {});
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

**Note**: That the red warning won't appear in production so it might actually be a viable solution.